# IndexOf behaves different than expected C#

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I've got the following three lines of code, with `html` being an html page stored as a string.

```
int startIndex = html.IndexOf("<title>") + 8; // <title> plus a space equals 8 characters
int endIndex = html.IndexOf("</title>") - 18; // -18 is because of the input, there are 18 extra characters after the username.
result = new Tuple<string, bool>(html.Substring(startIndex, endIndex), false);
```

With the input `<title>Username012345678912141618</title>` I would expect an output of `Username`. However, the code can't find the `</title>`. I'm not sure what's going wrong. Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour?
I've tested it with three different webpages (all from the same site), of which I inspected the content.

Comment: `-18`? Why are you subtracting -18 from the endIndex?

Comment: Oh, sorry, should've added that to the OP. There's always 18 characters of additional text between the username and the </title>. Like so:
<title> Username 12345678911131517</title>

Comment: @JasperMW The question still says "*With the input* `<title>Username</title>` ..." after your edit. So what `<title>` are you actually testing with?

Comment: @dxiv I can't post the name of the site online, sorry. It's <title>Username - Site name </title>

Comment: @JasperMW Just put `18` random characters there. The way it's written now "*With the input* `<title>Username</title>` *I would expect an output of* `Username`" that line directly contradicts your other comments and the answer you just accepted.

Comment: For a problem like that if you don't get what you expect, you can use a debugger, read the documentation or add some extra line of code to see intermediate steps results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Substring` with 2 parameters has next signature - `String.Substring(int startIndex, int length)` with second parameter being [the number of characters in the substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_). So you need to do something like this (taking in account your comment):

```
int startIndex = html.IndexOf("<title>") + 8;
int endIndex = html.IndexOf("</title>")
var result = new Tuple<string, bool>(html.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex - 18), false);
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a bunch! I don't need the -18 in de Substring (the code works without it), but aside from that this is great. I feel stupid, since I read the docs of IndexOf assuming the error was there.

Comment: @JasperMW was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I realize the OP was inquiring about the `IndexOf` method, but here is a solution that uses a different approach--Regular Expressions, which are perfectly suited "surgically" extract data from strings.

The following pattern is all that is needed to extract the "Username" from the html tag:

```
var pattern = $@"<title>Username(.+)</title>";
```

This pattern would be used as follows:

```
var pattern = $@"<title>Username(.+)</title>";
var ms = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var userName = ms.Groups.Count > 0 ? ms.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
```

One advantage of `Regex` is that you can use the exact text that you are using to search for the data you need. No need to fumble around with adding or subtracting "places" from the index.

You will need to add:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to the class you intend to implement `Regex`.